# iPad app crashed on every launch

Tags: ios, ipad

I am worling on am iPad application and the app getting crashed every time I launch. Below is my crash report published in the log.

```
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[5532] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[5532] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/268FC6CC-D5C3-4F9A-998E-0CB3158EC7A0 (sandbox)
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupApp
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: server
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppser
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupApppot
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppfarm
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppurlsuff
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppmac
Apr 12 12:43:44 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: activation code is 123
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppPort2
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppser2
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppdom2
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: inside setupAppuser
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: =================================================
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: onRegistrationStatusChanged: status = 202, code = 0, message = (null)
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Warning>: =================================================
Apr 12 12:43:45 iGATE-iPAD2 FieldService[5532] <Error>: SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress[Pair] called with invalid address family 1
Apr 12 12:44:04 iGATE-iPAD2 backboardd[26] <Warning>: com.igate.sapapps.fieldfinal failed to launch in time
Apr 12 12:44:04 iGATE-iPAD2 backboardd[26] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of FieldService[5532]...
Apr 12 12:44:05 iGATE-iPAD2 backboardd[26] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Apr 12 12:44:05 iGATE-iPAD2 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.igate.sapapps.fieldfinal[0x47a6][5532]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.igate.sapapps.fieldfinal[0x47a6]) Exited: Killed: 9
Apr 12 12:44:05 iGATE-iPAD2 backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.igate.sapapps.fieldfinal[0x47a6]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Apr 12 12:44:05 iGATE-iPAD2 ReportCrash[5535] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Apr 12 12:44:05 iGATE-iPAD2 ReportCrash[5535] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/FieldService_2014-04-12-124404_iGATE-iPAD2.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Apr 12 12:45:20 iGATE-iPAD2 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.ubd) <Notice>: (com.apple.ubd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 1 seconds
Apr 12 12:45:20 iGATE-iPAD2 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.ubd) <Notice>: (com.apple.ubd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 1 seconds
Apr 12 12:45:51 iGATE-iPAD2 locationd[46] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Apr 12 12:47:01 iGATE-iPAD2 locationd[46] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
Apr 12 12:49:05 iGATE-iPAD2 backboardd[26] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Apr 12 12:49:05 iGATE-iPAD2 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 0 (set level to 0x37e)
Apr 12 12:49:05 iGATE-iPAD2 backboardd[26] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
Apr 12 12:49:05 iGATE-iPAD2 profiled[5571] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
Apr 12 12:49:05 iGATE-iPAD2 profiled[5571] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Recomputing passcode requirement message
Apr 12 12:49:05 iGATE-iPAD2 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleMultitouchZ2SPI: updating power statistics
Apr 12 12:49:05 iGATE-iPAD2 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 0
Apr 12 12:50:05 iGATE-iPAD2 profiled[5571] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Idled.
Apr 12 12:50:05 iGATE-iPAD2 profiled[5571] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.`
```

Comment: You need to give us more. This is way to vague, it sounds like 'i have a problem' can  you help me. Tell us what your doing and what goes wrong. Im sure it was working at some point, so what did you that stopped it from working?

Comment: This project is not mine, someone else developed it. I need to add more functionality in it. From first day I am trying to run its not working because of this finally asking for help. Note: previous people   are not in company.

Comment: Have a look at 'called with invalid address family 1' that seems like some network issues. But its a wild shot. We need to have more otherwise its the 'needle in the haystack'. I would say, run in it with the debugger, step through it. And see where it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Apr 12 12:44:04 iGATE-iPAD2 backboardd[26] <Warning>: com.igate.sapapps.fieldfinal failed to launch in time
```

You're taking too long to launch. Do you have a long running process on launch? If so, you either should run that asynchronously so the launch can proceed as expected, or could make your root viewcontroller a 'loading' view that displays an activity indicator and executes the process, advancing to the intended view controller when the process completes.